# What is the total number of additions and multiplications in the following code?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm in a discrete math class and he explained very little about programming and code so far.  He also said he likes to throw in crazy questions to our homework to throw us off.  Thus, I'm here to learn from you for this particular question! (I don't know how to further research this question since I'm not sure what language this is, I think it might be C++?)

What is the total number of additions and multiplications in the following code?

```
s := 0
for i := 1 to n
    s:= s + i
    for j:= 1 to i
        s := s + j*i
    next j
next i
s := s+10


(a) n 
(b) n^2
(c) n^2 + 2n 
(d) n(n + 1)
(e) (n + 1)^2 
(f) none of these.
```

Comment: Not C++, looks like Pascal. Edit: @Bjørn Bråthen is probably right.

Comment: isn't it just psuedocode then?

Comment: @hatchet whyd you change my edit?

Comment: it's not pascal. "next i" looks more like visual basic

Comment: Yeah, it looks like Pasic. (a mix of pascal and basic)

Comment: @megawac Because it made it look like the final line was inside the i-loop. In basic, which uses the For/Next syntax, it's common to align the Next with its matching For.

Comment: SO is not a place to get your homework done, it is place to learn how to do your homework when you need help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are `n` additions to `s` in the outer loop, and `n(n+1)/2` inner iterations each containing an addition *and* a multiplication (multiply by 2), so `n^2 + n` operations in the inner loop plus the single addition at the end for a total of:

```
[n additions to s] + [n(n + 1) inner loop operations] + [the very last line]
= n + n(n+1) + 1
= n + n^2 + n + 1
= n^2 + 2n + 1
= (n + 1)^2 operations (e)
```

This is of course assuming that the implicit operations performed on `i` and `j` are not counted as additions. Presumably you wouldn't be asked to know how the compiler treats range-based loops.

Comment: what about the final line?

Comment: but, when n goes to infinity? ;)

Comment: Careful, there's a flaw in the logic for the number of inner iterations. On the first iteration of `for i := 1 to n`, `i` is 1; next time it's 2, etc. So the total iterations of the j-loop are 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = (n * (n+1)) / 2. (Using the good old-fashioned summation formula).

Comment: Looking like option F then?

Comment: @user2461994 no I was wrong. It's (e). See updated version from musical_coder's suggestion.